# Не работает IR приёмник

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Я собрал схему из стандартного IR приёмника, пищалки и реле. вся суть в том, что тогда, когда я нажимаю кнопку на пульте, не выполняется прописанное мной условие:

```
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16724175){
          digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
          }
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16718055){
          digitalWrite(2,LOW);
          }
```

---

Полный код:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <NewTone.h>

IRrecv ir_rx(8);
decode_results ir_rx_results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

  ir_rx.enableIRIn();

  NewTone(4, 1300, 50);

  delay(6000);

  NewTone(4, 1300, 1000);

  delay(4000);

  digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  delay(4000);

  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
}


void loop(){
  if (ir_rx.decode(&ir_rx_results)) {
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16724175){
          digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
          }
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16718055){
          digitalWrite(2,LOW);
          }
  }
}
```

---

***P.S. Плата: Arduino Uno, Реле: JQC-3FF-S-Z (На печатной плате с светодиодом).***

***Реле на пине 2, пищалка на 4, IR приёмник на 8.***

Comment: Попробуйте добавить Serial.println(ir_rx_result.value, DEC); в тело проверки.

Comment: У Arduino нет стандартной библиотеки для ИК https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries. О каком «стандартном» приемнике речь?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Речь не о библиотеке. Я говорю про приёмник ИК сигнала. Он используется почти везде, где нужно принимать ИК сигнал

Comment: ИК-приемников существует довольно много видов. Они могут отличаться по расположению контактов (нужно проверять правильность подключения), по напряжению питания, по модулирующей частоте (если она у приемника и передатчика отличается, то приемник вообще ничего не увидит).

Comment: А про библиотеку я написал потому, что для всей стандартной периферии есть стандартные библиотеки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примерам из библиотеки IRremote в цикле опроса и ожидания пропущен вызов `resume()`

```
void loop(){
  if (ir_rx.decode(&ir_rx_results)) {
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16724175){
          digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
          }
        if (ir_rx_results.value == 16718055){
          digitalWrite(2,LOW);
          }
        ir_rx.resume(); // <-- вот тут
  }
}
```

Comment: Точку с запятой забыли)